# Vertically Stacked Views with Static and Dynamic Heights - React Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I am trying to acheive what the image below represents with Flexbox in React Native with Views, if you have a basic example of this that would be amazing:

[image]

Comment: We don't write up code here, so show us what you got so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
  <View style={{ height: 70, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
  </View>
  <View style={{ height: 70, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
  </View>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
  </View>
</View>
```

Not sure if the blue lines are lines / padding / etc, but you should be able to add those into this shell.